# Python generate random steps for range function in each iteration of a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, random

I am trying to split a string into small chunks of random sizes. For example,

`string = 'qwertyuiopp'` into `['qw','e','rty,'u','iopp']`

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(args.fasta_file , "fasta"):
    step = 200
    for i in range(0, len(record),step):
        oline = ">"+record.id+"_"+str(i+1)+"\n"
        ofname.write(oline)
        step = random.randrange(200,2000)
        if len(record.seq[i:i+step]) >= 200:
            oline= str(record.seq[i:i+step])+"\n"
            ofname.write(oline)
        i=i+step
        else:
            oline= str(record.seq[i-200:])+"\n"
            ofname.write(oline)
        i=len(record)+1
```

I figure the problem is that the step in range function remains constant(200) inspite of modifying the value of step using randrange. but I dont know how I should go about this. Thank for any help.

Comment: try replacing random.randrange(200,2000) with random.randint(200,2000) .

Comment: Why don't you simply generate a random number of random indexes, sort the generated indices and then build the substrings?

Comment: @Bakuriu: Getting the same distribution with that approach isn't trivial.

Comment: Another thing try to comply with pep8 standard, that is typical for python scripts, it will help with readability: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @Drachenfels: It would help to give specifics of where he's going wrong (inconsistent spacing around operators). Someone who's really motivated might read through the whole doc and fix things, or find a checker tool like [`pep8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) and then look up the rules the checker flags, but that's a lot to expect.

Comment: I assumed that creator of question just did not know about pep8 existence. Maybe it's wrong assumption. If person that asks for advice knows it and deliberately choose to not follow them I still think it's good to link pep8 as some other person may read it and follow it. To summarize. My comment was not about white spaces (in particular) but rather lack of them made me think that pep8 might be unfamiliar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range` function creates a list as soon as the for loop is encountered. It does not get evaluated for every iteration.
You can use a `while` loop for this purpose.

```
import random
step = 1
count = 0
while count < len(record):     
    print count
    step = random.randint(1, 5)
    count += step
```

Comment: This is only true for Python 2.x. In 3.x, `range` create a `range` object, not a `list`. But the effect is the same: you get a `range(0, 1000, 200)` object, which won't magically change itself when `step` changes.

Answer (score 2):

The `range` function does not remember how it got the values it was constructed from. When you call `range(0, len(record), step)` that creates either the range object `range(0, 1000, 200)` (Python 3.x) or the list `[0, 200, 400, 600, 800]` (Python 2.x). Either way, changing `step` later isn't going to change anything.

You could build a custom iterator that that lets you reset its step, or one that changes its step and iterates `(start, end)` or `(start, step)` pairs. But that may be a little advanced for you.*

In that case, when you can't find or write an iterator to loop over, you have to go to a `while` loop, and update your loop variable manually.

It's worth noting that you're *already* trying to update your loop variable manually, with that `i = i + step`. That's usually a bad idea inside a `for` loop—but inside a `while` loop, it's exactly what you want. So really, just change this line:

```
for i in range(0, len(record),step):
```

… to these two lines:

```
i = 0
while i < len(record):
```

There are other problems in your code that you have to fix (including at least two `IndentationError`s), but you can fix them once you get past this.

One last thing: Whether you've got a `for` loop or a `while` loop, if you want to break out early, the way to do it is a `break` statement, not by trying to change the loop conditions so the next test will fail. So, replace that `i=len(record)+1` at the end with `break` as well.

---

* Also, the obvious implementation for such an iterator would be the same kind of `while` loop anyway…

Comment: The solution in this answer was already in senshin's, along with most of the explanation for the solution. Unfortunately, he deleted his answer, so I couldn't just refer to it.

Comment: @abernert Thank you very much for this elaborate answer and also for pointing out the problems in my code.